# Libertine and lettrine with pdflatex: strange error

Tags: libertine, lettrine, drop-cap

I have this package `lettrex.sty`

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
%
\RequirePackage{%
lettrine,%
ifthen,%
}
%
\setcounter{DefaultLines}{3}
\renewcommand{\DefaultLoversize}{0.07}
%
\DeclareOption{Libertine-Initials}{%
%X \renewcommand{\DefaultOptionsFile}{Libertine-Initials-Lettrinex.cfg}%
  \let\OldLettrine\lettrine%
  \renewcommand{\lettrine}[3][]{%
     \OldLettrine[#1]{\libertineInitialGlyph{#2}}{\MakeLowercase{#3}}%
  }%
}

\ProcessOptions\relax%
\endinput
```

and this config file `Libertine-Initials-Lettrinex.cfg`

```
    \LettrineOptionsFor{A}{findent=-0.8em,nindent=0.5em,loversize=0.07,slope=0.6em}
```

When I compile `pdflatex testL-In.tex`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[Libertine-Initials]{lettrex}

\begin{document}
\lettrine{A}{is a letter of our alphabet}. \blindtext
\end{document}
```

then all seems OK. But when I remove the `%X` in `lettrex.sty` to enable the options for letter 'A', I get this error:

```
(./testL-In.aux) (./Libertine-Initials-Lettrinex.cfg)
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.16 \lettrine{A}{is a letter of our alphabet}
                                              . \blindtext
? 

(/zfs/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/libertine/T1LinuxLibertineInitialsT-LF.
fd)
! Extra \endcsname.
\@lettrine ...er \ifx \csname l@#2-keys\endcsname 
                                                  \relax \gdef \l@LOKeys {}\...
l.16 \lettrine{A}{is a letter of our alphabet}
                                              . \blindtext
? 

Overfull \hbox (7.46712pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 16--17
[][]\T1/LinuxLibertineT-TLF/m/n/12 . Lorem ip-sum do-lor sit amet, con-sectetue
r
[1{/zfs/texlive/2022/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./testL-In.aux) ){/zfs/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/libertine/lbtn_
ncsllp.enc}{/zfs/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/libertine/lbtn_vsrqlo.
enc}{/zfs/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/libertine/lbtn_76gpa5.enc}</z
fs/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/libertine/LinLibertineIT.pfb></zf
s/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/libertine/LinLibertineT.pfb>
Output written on testL-In.pdf (1 page, 119263 bytes).
Transcript written on testL-In.log.
```

Finally it does give me the Initial, but what is done wrong here?

Comment: you are changing the second argument to `\libertineInitialGlyph{#2}`, and that means that lettrine doesn't look up a configuration for A with `\csname l@A-keys\endcsname` but tries to find `\csname l@\libertineInitialGlyph{A}-keys\endcsname` and that explodes.

Comment: Thanks Ulrike. As this goes beyond my TeX-kownledge: Is there a (hopefully simple) solution for this? Is there a way to access the libertine Initials other than by `\libertineInitialGlyph` in pdflatex?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to patch `\lettrine`, you can use the hooks provided by lettrine:

```
\begin{filecontents}{Libertine-Initials-Lettrinex.cfg}
\LettrineOptionsFor{A}{findent=-0.8em,nindent=0.5em,loversize=0.07,slope=0.6em}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[optionsfile=Libertine-Initials-Lettrinex.cfg]{lettrine}
\renewcommand\LettrineFontHook{\libertineInitial}
\renewcommand\LettrineTextFont{\MakeLowercase}
\begin{document}

\lettrine{A}{IS A LETTER OF OUR ALPHABET}. %uppercase for demo
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the second argument is used to check whether the particular initial is associated to some code in the `.cfg` file and passing it `\libertineInitialGlyph{<letter>}` breaks.

You need to patch something else, namely `\setupL@lbox`, where the typeset initial is stored.

I don't think you really want `\MakeLowercase` for the second argument.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\RequirePackage{lettrine}

\setcounter{DefaultLines}{3}
\renewcommand{\DefaultLoversize}{0.07}

\DeclareOption{Libertine-Initials}{%
  \renewcommand{\DefaultOptionsFile}{Libertine-Initials-Lettrinex.cfg}%
  \def\setupL@lbox{%
    \computeL@height
    \ifL@image
      \sbox{\L@lbox}{\LettrineImage{\l@initial}}%
    \else
      \compute@fontsize
      \sbox{\L@lbox}{\LettrineFont\libertineInitialGlyph{\l@initial}}%
    \fi
  }%
}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\endinput
```

[image]

Probably you can remove `\LettrineFont`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to patch anything, just change your `lettrex.sty` file:

```
\begin{filecontents}{Libertine-Initials.cfg}
\LettrineOptionsFor{A}{findent=-0.8em,
    nindent=0.5em,loversize=0.07,slope=0.6em}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{lettrex.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\RequirePackage{%
  lettrine,%
  iftex,%
}

\setcounter{DefaultLines}{3}
\renewcommand{\DefaultLoversize}{0.07}

\DeclareOption{Libertine-Initials}{%
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{%
              \fontfamily{LinuxLibertineInitialsT-LF}}
\renewcommand{\DefaultOptionsFile}{Libertine-Initials.cfg}
}
\ifpdftex
  \DeclareOption{Libertine-Initials}{%
  \renewcommand\LettrineFontHook{%
               \fontfamily{LinuxLibertineInitialsT-LF}}
  \renewcommand{\DefaultOptionsFile}{Libertine-Initials.cfg}
  }
\else
  \DeclareOption{Libertine-Initials}{%
  \renewcommand\LettrineFontHook{\fontspec{LinLibertine_I.otf}}
  \renewcommand{\DefaultOptionsFile}{Libertine-Initials.cfg}
 }
\fi

\ProcessOptions\relax
\endinput
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[Libertine-Initials]{lettrex}

\begin{document}
\lettrine{A}{is a letter of our alphabet}. \blindtext
\end{document}
```

produces no error message and outputs

[image]

If you don't want small caps for the second argument of `\lettrine`, just add
`\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{\relax}`

Comment: Thanks Daniel, this is the simple solution I was looking for. I have a related question though: When I want Old Style Figures, and do `\usepackage[osf]{libertine}` then the Initials font is not found anymore. Is there a (simple?) way of combining osf with libertine-initials while using the package lettrex?

Comment: The `libertine` package wrongly forwards the `osf` option to the `LinuxLibertineInitials` font.  I have patched my answer to overcome this glitch.

Comment: Note that the patch is not necessary if you compile with a "modern" engine `luatex` or `xetex`.

Comment: Thanks again. I know, but I'm building a small package and want to support pdflatex as well. I think still a lot of people do use that, due to its compiling speed, which is superior to the newer engines. That at least is the main reason I still use pdflatex

Comment: The above code works for both pdflatex and lualatex, so you will be still able to use it if you ever change your mind ;-)  Note that the way of calling `LinuxLibertineInitials` differs for pdflatex against lualatex/xeltex.